# Using InStr in Access VBA to lookup a string value from another table

Tags: dictionary, ms-access, instr

Very new to access VBA and would love some guidance on this.

I am searching through a string and looking for a particular substring in this field.  This substring would have a value based on another table, ie

order = "Reference order QQ131415"

The problem is, there is no particular pattern for order numbers.  Some are 7 digits, some are 10 and some have dashes in there.

There is a table i have access too that has these order numbers though, and I guess I am trying to use that table as  a dictionary.

my very very basic Access VBA code is like this

' order= Instr(1, rst![order], qst![order_id],vbBinaryCompare)'

order is the string where i have the order id i am trying to extract
order_id is the actual id from a seperate table.

Is this something that Access VBA can handle?

Answer (score 0):

So i think this will help [you](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function)

You're not very clear in the sentence following on from "order=" with your code. Could you clear that up.

Instr(string1, String2, [ compare ])

string1 Required. String expression being searched.
string2 Required. String expression sought.

Instr returns a Variant (number in this case) specifying the position of the first occurrence of one string within another. So it should be:
Position= InStr(1, string1, string2, 1)

So you'd now know that the ordernumber starts at position x in Order. You'd then have to do a left(Order, Len(order) -x) to extract the string.

Youd do that in a nested loop because youll have to loop through your dictionary per record in Order.

E.g.

```
Dim rsOrder as DAO.recordset
Dim rsOrderId as Dao.recordset
dim orderTest as integer
dim stringcapture as string

Set rsOrder = Currentdb.OpenRecordset("[SELECT STRING]")
rsOrder.Movefirst

Do until rsOrder.EOF or rsOrder.BOF
    Order = rsOrder![OrderFieldName]
    Set rsOrderId = Currentdb.OpenRecordSet("[SELECT STRING]")
    rsOrderID.Movefirst
    Do Until rsOrderID.EOF or rsOrderID.BOF
        OrderID = rsOrderID![OrderIDFieldName]
        orderTest = Instr(1, Order, OrderID,1)
        StringCapture = left(Order, Len(order) -OrderTest)
    rsOrderID.movenext
    Loop
rsOrder.movenext
Loop
rsOrder.close
rsOrderID.close
```

Something to that affect.